# vbscrip ADODB.RecordSet RecordCount Not Working Correctly

Tags: vbscript, ado

I'm trying to return the number of records from the following SQL Query Output:

> SELECT status, total_elapsed_time, text FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
>   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) WHERE status = 'running'
>   AND text like '%Insert%' AND total_elapsed_time > '1'

When i'm manually running the SQL Query in SSMS, sometimes i have and output and sometime not.

This is the IF condition in my Script:

```
If Not (objRS.BOF AND objRS.EOF) then objRS.MoveFirst               
Do Until objRS.EOF
                if objRS.RecordCount > 0 then

                                 '#objAPI.LogScriptEvent 
                                 Call oBag.AddValue("State","BAD")
                                 Call oBag.AddValue("TotalElapsedTime",CustomValue1)
                                 Call objAPI.Return(oBag)
                else
                                 '#objAPI.LogScriptEvent 
                                 Call oBag.AddValue("State","GOOD")
                                 Call oBag.AddValue("TotalElapsedTime",CustomValue1)
                                 Call objAPI.Return(oBag)
                end if
                objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
```

For some reason,i'm getting opposite values from my vbscript:

When there is an output (RecordCount > 0), i'm getting the 'GOOD' value instead of 'BAD' value.

And when there is no output,
Sometime i'm getting blank output from the script and sometime i'm getting Instead an the following Error Message when there is no output:

> C:\Users\TEMP.RESOURCE.004\Desktop\SMSHafatzaLongRun.vbs(35, 1)
>   ADODB.Field: Eit her BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has
>   been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: Can you debug and check if `objRS.RecordCount` returns a value > 0

Comment: Hey Pankaj, i will debug this property an update as soon as possible thanks

Comment: This makes no sense you want to return a single recordcount but you are trying to loop through the recordset, why? You could have just used `If Not (objRS.BOF = False And objRS.EOF = False) Then` to check the recordset has records, then pulled the `objRS.RecordCount` property. Suggest you provide a [mcve] so we can test this ourselves. As it stands anyone will just be guessing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also to loop a recordset you need to do `Do While Not objRS.EOF` because you want to loop while you have data and have **not** reached the “End Of File”.